# Decrypt a ciphertext with Python that was encrypted using PHP

Tags: python, php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a ciphertext that was encrypted using PHP which I need to decrypt using Python.
I have the below PHP code that decrypts the ciphertext perfectly.

```php
$cryptText = "ciphertext";
$iv = "some iv"
$cipher = new Crypt_Rijndael(CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_MODE_CFB);

$password = "some password";
$salt = "some salt";

$cipher->setPassword($password, 'pbkdf2', 'sha512', $salt, 1000, 256 / 8);
$cipher->setIV($iv);
$plaintext = $cipher->decrypt(base64_decode($cryptText));
```

Now to decrypt it using Python I used 2 approaches

1. Using pyaes

```py
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import hashlib
import pyaes
import os

ciphertext = 'ciphertext'
ciphertext = b64decode(ciphertext)

password = b'some password'
salt = b'some salt'
iv=b'some iv'

key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password, salt, 1000, 32)

aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCFB(key, iv = iv)
decryptedData = aes.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

2. PyCryptodome (`Crypto.Cipher.AES`)

```py
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

ciphertext = 'ciphertext'
ciphertext = b64decode(ciphertext)

password = b'some password'
salt = b'some salt'
iv=b'some iv'

key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password, salt, 1000, 32)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
decryptedData = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

The result from 1 and 2 is same but not matching the one from PHP

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code uses a different segment size<sup>1)</sup> than the two Python codes: The *phpseclib v1* specifies with `CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_MODE_CFB` the CFB mode with a segment size of 128 bits (full-block CFB), while *PyCryptodome* and *pyaes* use a segment size of 8 bits by default.
Therefore, a ciphertext that can be decrypted with the PHP code cannot be decrypted with either Python code. For this to be possible, the segment size must be explicitly set to 128 bits in the Python codes,

- for *PyCryptodome*:

  ```
  cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv=iv, segment_size=128)
  ```
- for *pyaes*:

  ```
  cipher = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCFB(key, iv=iv, segment_size=16)
  ```

  Note that for *pyaes* the segment size is specified in bytes and not in bits. Furthermore, *pyaes* requires that the plaintext must be an integer multiple of the segment size, i.e. for full-block CFB an integer multiple of 16 bytes.

---

<sup>1)</sup> The segment size of the CFB mode corresponds to the bits encrypted per encryption step, see [CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_(CFB)).